# switching to different crypto library

Tags: javascript, cryptography

have a block of code that used CryptoJS as an npm dependency in a project, but my security team is asking that I switch libraries to something like msrcrypto.

```
  // let secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("storageaccountaccesskeyfromAzureViaEnvironmentVariable");
  // let hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
  // let hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```

The goal is to build the Authentication header as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key . The CryptoJS approach has worked thus far for me.

Can anyone help? I've tried using the samples I see in the HTML, but I don't understand many of the words in the HMAC example. I got to that point via tutorials online for the Microsoft Authentication header but don't personally understand much of it.

I've tried to capture some example output for those 3 steps and see if I can generate the same with NodeJS's Buffer.from to get into and out of base64, but I've yet to see the same output as what I see from CryptoJS.

Comment: This is more a "port my code" question than anything else; crypto primitives have been defined to be byte-compatible. Could you at least update your title to something less generic? I would expect the word "HMAC" in there, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which computes `HMACSHA256(secret: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], message: [7, 8, 9, 10])`. Both libs produce the same result:

```js
const secret = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const data = [7, 8, 9, 10];

// msrcrypto
const algorithm = {
    name: 'HMAC',
    hash: {
        name: 'SHA-256'
    }
};
const jwkKey = {
    kty: "oct",
    alg: "HS256",
    k: msrCrypto.toBase64(secret),
    ext: true
};
// I don't know why, but with async mode I am getting an error in my browser
// with no meaningful message
msrCrypto.subtle.forceSync = 1;
msrCrypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", jwkKey, algorithm, true, ['sign', 'verify']).then(key => {
    msrCrypto.subtle.sign(algorithm, key, data).then(hmac => {
        const arr = new Uint8Array(hmac);
        console.log('msrCrypto: ' + msrCrypto.toBase64(arr));
    });
});

// cryptojs
const cryptoJsSecret = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(new Uint8Array(secret));
const cryptoJsData = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(new Uint8Array(data));
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(cryptoJsData, cryptoJsSecret);
console.log('CryptoJS: ' + CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/msrcrypto@1.5.3/msrcrypto.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am now running into issues even running this code from my main process of my Electron app which is trying to use this code. Also the only major difference I see is that my code is an Azure access key, and my first line with CryptoJS needs to read it in from base64, I believe. How is that done here? Just msrCrypto.fromBase64()?

Comment: The other option I have is to do this with webcrypto which seems to follow Crypto in NodeJS according to my security team. Any idea how I may use that instead?

Comment: I did it! I'll post an answer that shows the comparison across the two libraries I used.

Answer (score 1):

```
  let secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("azureAccessKeyInBase64" as string);
  let hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
  let hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
  let auth = "SharedKey storageaccount:" + hashInBase64;

  console.log("auth: " + auth);

  let secret2 = Buffer.from("azureAccessKeyInBase64" as string, 'base64');
  let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret2);
  hmac.write(strToSign);
  hmac.end();
  let hash2 = hmac.read();
  let hash2InBase64 = Buffer.from(hash2).toString('base64');
  let auth2 = "SharedKey storageaccount:" + hash2InBase64;
  console.log("auth2: " + auth);
```

Auth2 shows as equal to auth for me with this code :)